# How to Call a boot method only after email is verified in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i want to be able to call a boot method like the one shown below only after user has verified email.

```
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function ($project) {
            // create row in another table
        });

    }
```

i want to insert a new row into another table only after user has verified email. so is there any method that can make this happen.

Comment: use `$project->isDirty('some_property')` to determine if it has changed? I'm unsure what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You want to access the User from the Auth helper and therefrom update your other model. Be aware that the Auth needs to be used in Http context with authorization and will not work in commands and jobs.

```
static::created(function ($project) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user && $user->email_verified) {
        AnotherModel::create([
           // your fields
        ]);
    }
});
```